# Taxation after money received into UK bank account while not living/working there

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, foreign-income, hungary

I've lived and worked for a year in the UK, received salary and paid taxes there, but I returned to my home country.

I'm about to receive money for a work I've conducted for a foreign entity who'll wire money for me as payment from a UK account. (I haven't worked as an employee for them; I'll receive an advance on future royalties and if everything goes well more royalties.)

Is there a threshold under which I can receive such payments to my UK bank account without worrying about accidental tax avoidance?

Anything to watch out for?

Comment: Which country are you in currently (and presumably paying taxes in now)?  If you're no longer tax resident in the UK then it's more likely a matter for your current country's tax regime; details might depend on what tax-treaty your current country has with the UK though.

Comment: @timday I reside in Hungary. There's a double tax treaty in effect between the two countries. Hmm. So I would need to study this I guess? :) https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/hungary-tax-treaties

Comment: Seems to me that the only thing you probably need to worry about is taxation in Hungary.  I wouldn't have thought UK taxation had anything to do with it unless the entity paying you has taken some UK taxes (e.g PAYE, NI) off already and you want to avoid double taxation.

Comment: @timday As I don't receive this money as an employee I don't think they pay any kind of taxes after me. I'll look into it :) Thanks!